# SOAP output processing

Tags: php, xml, soap

i am calling a soap based web service in php.

when i echo the output nothing can be seen on the page, but i can see a xml in viewsouce.
Can anyone guide me in processing the output so that i can appropriate data from it. I have never dealt with xml before so finding it a bit confusing.

Here's my code

```
$a = new SoapClient('http://abc.com?wsdl');
$login = $a ->TestConnectStr(array('UserName' => 'Test', 'Password' => '1234'));
echo $login->TestConnectStrResult;
```

the output link view-source:http://www.toolbrands.co.uk/rialto.php

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unless you output an appropriate content-type header, the xml tags will be interpreted as unknown html tags, and simply be ignored by the browser. try `header('Content-type: text/plain')` before doing your echo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that your  given web service method **$a ->TestConnectStr();** returns a XML string . if you print the resulted string using **echo**  the browser will render the xml tags . if want the see xml out put **for testing purpose** you can print those values to a textarea like this

> > $xml= $login->TestConnectStrResult;
> >
> > echo "< textarea cols=50 rows=10> $xml < /textarea> ";

if you need do any operations on resulted xml string you need to parse that xml